# Searching for the name of a specific menu - Flutter

Tags: flutter, menu

So I'm searching for a Menu often found in a Settings Screen. It's used to select a Setting.
It opens when you press on a ListTile and then it fills the mayority of the Screen, while the borders are transparent. In the menu you have to select one of the options.
An example usecase of that would be to select a Language(onTap of the ListTile opens a Menu where you can select between all the avaliable languages)

It is similar to that of a PopupMenuButton, however as already mentioned it fills most of the screen, and the individual selectable items have a radiobutton in front of the text(probably RadioListTiles)

I hope someone gets what I'm talking about, because for the past 3 hours I'm searching for this widget but just find articles about the PopupMenuButton over and over.

Edit: I finally found an app that uses the feature I'm looking for
: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFPeS.jpg
By clicking on the first ListTile in the first Picture, the dialog in the second picture opens up.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this custom widget is something roughly what you want, try to copy and paste it in your project and play with it.

this is made using the Dialog widget, to exit the Dialog you can tap out of it/ press the device back arrow and I added a small back icon on the top left corner.

tell me if it helped :)

```
class TestPage extends StatelessWidget {
```

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

```
final deviceSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;// the device size
return Scaffold(
  body: Center(
    child: ListTile(
      tileColor: Colors.grey[300],
      title: Text(
        'Language',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
      ),
      onTap: () => showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => Dialog(
          insetPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            height: deviceSize.height,
            width: deviceSize.width,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    IconButton(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                      onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Spacer(),
                Text('Pick A Language'),
                Spacer(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}
}

Comment: with a bit of playing around I could probably get close, but the feature im looking for is one I have seen often and I would asume there is a premade Widget for that. https://imgur.com/a/A9k71io here is i picture of the menu I'm talking about.

Comment: try this:     https://pub.dev/packages/adaptive_dialog     . looks like the closest thing to what you search for. ^_^